# Имеется ли какое-то готовое решение для распознания текста на изображении в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, распознавание-символов

Я написал парсер, который собирает изображения c разрешением 1280x720 по ключевому слову с поисковой выдачи Яндекса. Проблема в том, что порой попадаются изображения, на которых имеется текст (заголовок новости, водяной знак, название соцсети и т.п.). Мне такие изображения ни к чему, и надобно их удалить. Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли какая-либо библиотека, которая смогла бы мне облегчить жизнь, чтобы я мог быстро обработать результаты парсинга и удалить ненужные изображения? Все что я нагуглил все не то, пока что. Возможно посоветуете API сервиса какого-то?

Comment: есть OCR от гугла. https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изучая вопрос по обнаружению текста в изображении, я натолкнулся на интересную статью  Adrian Rosebrock, которую вы можете изучить на его блоге: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/20/opencv-text-detection-east-text-detector/. А также нашел любопытную статью другого автора: https://towardsdatascience.com/read-text-from-image-with-one-line-of-python-code-c22ede074cac